# How to use analyze-string in xpath 3.1

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsd

Supposing I want to convert something like "03:02:22:11" into milliseconds. How do I do this with Xpath 3.1?

I have tried: analyze-string(/pc:podcast/pc:episode/pc:chapter, [(([0-9]?[0-9]:)?([0-5]?[0-9]:))?([0-5]?[0-9])(.[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?)?] without any result.

Below is my xml-file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<pc:podcast
    xmlns:pc="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast/0.3"
    xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast/0.3
        podcast.xsd
        https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1
        podcast-transcript.xsd"
    url="https://forschergeist.de/"
    version="0.3">

    <pc:title>Forschergeist</pc:title>

    <pc:persons>
        <pc:person pid="timpritlove" gender="male">Tim Pritlove</pc:person>
        <pc:person pid="ritaadrian" gender="female">Rita Adrian</pc:person>
        <pc:person pid="peterpurgathofer" gender="male">Peter Purgathofer</pc:person>
        <pc:person pid="justushaucap" gender="male">Justus Haucap</pc:person>
        <pc:person pid="oliverparodi" gender="male">Oliver Parodi</pc:person>
        <pc:person pid="alinakokoschka" gender="female">Alina Kokoschka</pc:person>
    </pc:persons>

    <pc:episode episode="73" title="Klimawandel in Seen" date="2019-11-19T19:35:00" url="https://forschergeist.de/podcast/fg073-klimawandel-in-seen/" duration="01:23:14">
        <pc:contributor pid="timpritlove" role="host"/>
        <pc:contributor pid="ritaadrian" role="guest" />

        <pc:chapter number="1" duration="00:41" title="Intro" />
        <pc:chapter number="2" duration="01:14" title="Begrüßung" />
        <pc:chapter number="3" duration="04:41" title="Leibniz-Institut für Gewässerökologie und Binnenfischerei " />
        <pc:chapter number="4" duration="02:35" title="Persönlicher Werdegang" />
        <pc:chapter number="5" duration="04:44" title="Wissenschaftskultur in den USA" />
        <pc:chapter number="6" duration="06:34" title="Das Ökosystem der Binnenseen" />
        <pc:chapter number="7" duration="15:04" title="Langzeitbeobachtung der Seen" />
        <pc:chapter number="8" duration="12:46" title="Erkenntnisse aus den Messungen" />
        <pc:chapter number="9" duration="08:27" title="Veränderungen durch den Klimawandel" />
        <pc:chapter number="10" duration="03:10" title="Erforderliche Maßnahmen" />
        <pc:chapter number="11" duration="11:52" title="Wissenschaftliche Arbeit im IPCC" />
        <pc:chapter number="12" duration="10:02" title="Datenmanagement" />
        <pc:chapter number="13" duration="01:06" title="Ausklang" />

        <pt:transcript 
            xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1"
            version="0.1">
        </pt:transcript>
    </pc:episode>

    <pc:episode episode="72" title="Verantwortung in der Informatik" date="2019-10-01T11:00:00" url="https://forschergeist.de/podcast/fg072-verantwortung-in-der-informatik/" duration="01:53:23">
        <pc:contributor pid="timpritlove" role="host"/>
        <pc:contributor pid="peterpurgathofer" role="guest" />

        <pc:chapter number="1" duration="00:42" title="Intro" />
        <pc:chapter number="2" duration="00:46" title="Begrüßung" />
        <pc:chapter number="3" duration="08:26" title="Peter Purgathofer" />
        <pc:chapter number="4" duration="09:26" title="Ethik und Moral in der Informatik" />
        <pc:chapter number="5" duration="06:41" title="Entscheidung und Verantwortung" />
        <pc:chapter number="6" duration="11:22" title="Denkweisen in der Informatik" />
        <pc:chapter number="7" duration="00:55" title="Strukturierung des Kurses" />
        <pc:chapter number="8" duration="05:31" title="Pre-Scientific Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="9" duration="04:15" title="Scientific Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="10" duration="06:01" title="Mathematical Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="11" duration="07:35" title="Computational Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="12" duration="09:57" title="Design Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="13" duration="10:20" title="Critical Thinking und Diversity" />
        <pc:chapter number="14" duration="05:15" title="Responsible Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="15" duration="04:00" title="Creative Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="16" duration="02:18" title="Economical Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="17" duration="04:07" title="Criminal Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="18" duration="02:07" title="Denkweisen für die Wissenschaft" />
        <pc:chapter number="19" duration="11:45" title="Der Reifegrad der Informatik" />
        <pc:chapter number="20" duration="01:43" title="Ausklang" />
  </pc:episode> 
    </pc:podcast>
```

Ho can I use analyze-string for all the @duration attributes in pc:chapter to convert them into milliseconds?

Short Update: I have implemented something like this:

`let $string :=analyze-string(string(//pc:episode[1]/@duration), "(([0-9]?[0-9]:)?([0-5]?[0-9]:))?([0-5]?[0-9])(\.[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?)?" ) return xs:integer($string[1])*3600000 + xs:integer($string[2])*60000 + xs:decimal($string[3] || '.' || $string[4])*1000`

But now I get the error Unable to perform XPath operation. Cannot convert string "01:23:14" to an integer, so I must doing something wrong but I do not know what.

Thanks for the Xpath guide but that doesn't solve my question ( I need to figure out that whenever something like 13:23 appears then he should convert this to milliseconds else when the string is something like '12:32:32.221' then he should transform that into milliseconds: if(string(/pc:podcast/pc:episode[1]/@duration != '00:00:00') then...

Here are some examples how the Xpath-Expression should handle this:

```
0.444 → 444 (0 * 1000 + 0.444 * 1000)
12.23 → 12230 (12 * 1000 + 0.23 * 1000 + 0.0 * 1000)
12:46 → 766.000 (12 * 60 * 1000 + 46 * 1000 + 0.0 * 1000)
01:53:23 → 6803000 (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + 53 * 60 * 1000 + 23 * 1000 + 0.0 * 1000)
01:53:23.123 → 6803123 (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + 53 * 60 * 1000 + 23 * 1000 + 0.123 * 1000)
```

I've tried also this and it seems to work: 
`let $string :=tokenize(string(//pc:episode[1]/@duration), ':') return xs:integer($string[1])*3600000 + xs:integer($string[2])*60000 + xs:decimal($string[3] || '.' || $string[4])*1000`

Comment: please let me know if the question is unclear for you

Comment: Do you have access to any software that provides an XPath 3.1 API? Saxon 9 (9.8 and later for XPath 3.1) has one. So that would answer the general question on how to use XPath 3.1 outside of XSLT. As for the problem of converting durations to milliseconds, why do you want to solve that with `analyze-string`?

Comment: @Martin Honnen Because we(i am a college student) have to use the analyze-string function. Furthermore we have to use an if else-statement for differentiation between hours and minutes). All this can be done with the tool XPath-Tester.(linkhttps://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Comment: That tool doesn't seem to support XPath 3.1, only 3.0. But if you have a tool to test/evaluate pure XPath 3 then use it and don't ask about "without xslt" in your question. And if it is your homework then I guess you have to work it out on your own.

Comment: I suggest you start reading an XPath tutorial, see https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3/other-expressions#conditional-expressions for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Supposing I want to convert something like "03:02:22:11" into milliseconds. How do I do this with Xpath 3.1?

Firstly you haven't explained the semantics. Presumably this means 3 hours, 2 minutes, 22.11 seconds?

I would do

```
let $t := tokenize($input, ':')
return xs:integer($t[1])*3600000 + 
       xs:integer($t[2])*60000 + 
       xs:decimal($t[3] || '.' || $t[4])*1000
```

I can't see why you would want to use `fn:analyze-string` for this.

An alternative would be

```
xs:dayTimeDuration(replace($input, '(..):(..):(..):(..)', 'PT$1H$2M$3.$4S'))
    div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S')
```

Comment: yes this seems to be a plausible answer. Hovewever my goal is to use fn:analyze-string in combination with the if-then-else Expression(and a let Expression for variables). One more question: How can I convert the miliseconds back to standart form(HH:MM:SS:Milliseconds) using div and mod and string-joint?

Comment: So how can I use the if-else.function then to determine whether hours and minutes are in the string? Sorry for the question but we don't covered this topic before and the lecturer/docent haven't explained it either. I want something like "if(hours and minutes are in the string) then tokenize/fn:analyze-string and return an integer value of the string.

Comment: By all means edit the question to provide a more precise specification of the problem. But please don't change the question by commenting on an answer. It's generally best, if you want to change the question, to start again from the beginning with a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would exploit the `xs:time` and `xs:duration` data types and their supported arithmetics operation:

```
let $time := xs:time('01:53:23.123'), $midnight := xs:time('00:00:00'), $duration := $time - $midnight return ($duration, $duration div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
let $string :="01:53:23.123", $regexpress :="(([0-9]?[0-9]):?([0-5]?[0-9])):?([0-5]?[0-9])(\.[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?)?" return xs:integer(analyze-string($string, $regexpress)//fn:group[@nr="2"]/string())*3600000+xs:integer(analyze-string($string, $regexpress)//fn:group[@nr="3"]/string())*60000 + xs:integer(analyze-string($string, $regexpress)//fn:group[@nr="4"]/string())*1000 + xs:decimal(analyze-string($string, $regexpress)//fn:group[@nr="5"]/string())*1000
```

Now I only need somehow the if then else expression...